# Highcharts navigator range is changed to range within extremes after series.update

Tags: highcharts

After performing the code below which changes display properties of the lines:

```
 chart.series[seriesIndex].update({             
                    color: Color,
                    dashStyle: getDashStyle(LineOptions.Type),
                    lineWidth: LineOptions.Thickness,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: LineOptions.Thickness,
                        }
                    },
                    dataGrouping: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }, true);
                this.chart.redraw();
```

The navigator changes start and end times (lines update fine).
Initial:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQmBi.png
After the redraw:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Etf.png

Initial navigator is set up with 2 data points, the start date and end date calculated and sent from the server. Not all data points are loaded due to a very large data size, only the ones which should be displayed on the user screen. Could this cause the issue with the navigator? If so, is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Maybe you update also a navigator series? If you could setup live demo with static data, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @paweł-fus I should mention the code was migrated from version 2 to v5. I am using this.chart.scroller.baseSeries with custom navigation buttons to select chart data. According to documentation this option is now deprecated, could it cause issues with navigator?

Comment: That could be, it's hard to say without working on the live example.

Comment: I created a fiddle representing what is happening with my data and I have reproduced the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/kjsL7/1/ As far as I am aware this issue did not exist in v2, whats the best way to avoid it? Ad time start and end datapoints which will prevent the navigator from shrinking? Or is there a way to disable navigator update on Series.update?

Comment: @paweł-fus This could be a slightly better example http://jsfiddle.net/kjsL7/5/

Comment: Thank you for the demo! That's right, it's a breaking change since 5.0.0, where each series can be rendered in the navigator. The best practice is to use [`navigator.series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.series) with a separate dataset. Also, I suggest to use `extremes.dataMin` and `extremes.dataMax` if you want to zoom into the new dataset. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kjsL7/8/